# Fancyhdr and Two Columns

Tags: header-footer

Is there a conflict between the [twocolumn] option and the \fancyhdr package?

The running header on the right side of the page throws the letter 'I' instead of a running header consistent with the different text on that page. The left side running header is fine.

This is the code, I apologize for its length; it was automatically generated by Pandoc. I've gone through it and can't figure out what's causing the error.

It has to be something in the Preamble, I tried a MWE with just the heading section and the fancyhdr package and the headers ran properly.

Here is a picture showing the offending character 'I' (or is it a '[' on the right)

[image]

```
So here is the code if anyone has any ideas:
% Options for packages loaded elsewhere
\PassOptionsToPackage{unicode}{hyperref}
\PassOptionsToPackage{hyphens}{url}

\documentclass[twocolumn,a4paper,9pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

%% fonts

%\usepackage{crimson}
%\usepackage{nimbusserif}

\usepackage{fontspec}
    \setmainfont{Biblia Serif}

\usepackage{iftex}
\ifPDFTeX
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
  \usepackage{textcomp} % provide euro and other symbols
\else % if luatex or xetex
  \usepackage{unicode-math}
  \defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase}
  \defaultfontfeatures[\rmfamily]{Ligatures=TeX,Scale=1}
\fi
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%  Headers

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{extramarks}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\pagestyle{headings}
\fancyhead[L]{\nouppercase{\rightmark}}
\fancyhead[R]{\nouppercase{\leftmark}}
\addtolength{\headwidth}{\marginparsep}

%%%%%%%%%% Lists

 \usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{paralist}  %%% compactenum
\usepackage{lipsum}

% Use upquote if available, for straight quotes in verbatim     environments
\IfFileExists{upquote.sty}{\usepackage{upquote}}{}
\IfFileExists{microtype.sty}{% use microtype if available
  \usepackage[]{microtype}
  \UseMicrotypeSet[protrusion]{basicmath} % disable protrusion    for tt fonts
}{}
\makeatletter
\@ifundefined{KOMAClassName}{% if non-KOMA class
  \IfFileExists{parskip.sty}{%
    \usepackage{parskip}
  }{% else
    \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
    \setlength{\parskip}{6pt plus 2pt minus 1pt}}
}{% if KOMA class
  \KOMAoptions{parskip=half}}
\makeatother
\usepackage{xcolor}
\IfFileExists{xurl.sty}{\usepackage{xurl}}{} % add URL line    breaks if available
\IfFileExists{bookmark.sty}{\usepackage{bookmark}}    {\usepackage{hyperref}}
\hypersetup{
  hidelinks,
  pdfcreator={LaTeX via pandoc}}
\urlstyle{same} % disable monospaced font for URLs
\usepackage{longtable,booktabs,array}
 \usepackage{calc} % for calculating minipage widths
% Correct order of tables after \paragraph* or \subparagraph
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd\longtable{\par}{\if@noskipsec\mbox{}\fi\par}{}{}
\makeatother
% Allow footnotes in longtable head/foot
\IfFileExists{footnotehyper.sty}{\usepackage{footnotehyper}}      {\usepackage{footnote}}
 \makesavenoteenv{longtable}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\makeatletter
 \def\maxwidth{\ifdim\Gin@nat@width>\linewidth\linewidth\else\Gin@nat@    width\fi}
  \def\maxheight{\ifdim\Gin@nat@height>\textheight\textheight\else\Gin@    nat@height\fi}
\makeatother
% Scale images if necessary, so that they will not overflow the page
% margins by default, and it is still possible to overwrite the     defaults
% using explicit options in \includegraphics[width, height, ...]    {}
 \setkeys{Gin}{width=\maxwidth,height=\maxheight,keepaspectratio}
% Set default figure placement to htbp
\makeatletter
\def\fps@figure{htbp}
\makeatother
\setlength{\emergencystretch}{3em} % prevent overfull lines
\providecommand{\tightlist}{%
  \setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-\maxdimen} % remove section numbering
\ifLuaTeX
  \usepackage{selnolig}  % disable illegal ligatures
\fi

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%  Extra

\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{tocloft}
%\usepackage{savetrees}

\author{}
\date{}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% End Preamble
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

%\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\tableofcontents

\hypertarget{introduction}{%
\section{Introduction}\label{introduction}}
\sectionmark{Introduction}

\lipsum{20}


\section{ANTI-MONEY LAUNDERING AND COUNTER-TERRORIST FINANCING RULES}
\sectionmark{AML RULES}

\lipsum[20]
\end{document}
```

I also tried using the Koma class, scrbook and removing all the "headings" entries save

```
\pagestyle{headings}
```

but this was the result.

enter image description here

[image]

[image]

Removing section line from preamble:

[image]

Update: In the Koma class at least; the "0 [" has been replaced by the word "Contents" on all verso pages. Now all I have to do is change "Contents" to correspond to the content on the page. The document started out under the Article class, which doesn't have chapter headings, but it is easy enough to substitute "Chapter" for "Section" in the book classes. But will this get rid of the word "Contents" in the running header?

Changing "section" to "Chapter" fixed the problem, or at least removed the word "Contents" and substituted the name of the Chapter.

Comment: the code is faulty, the \ifPDFTeX has no closing \fi. Beside this it doesn't show your problem, as there is nowhere the text "AML".

Comment: Like @UlrikeFischer , I can't reproduce the problem using the code provided. However, the symbol at the right of your image looks like an opening square bracket to me. You sometimes get this sort of problem if you try to pass optional arguments to commands that don't accept them. Without an example that reproduces the problem, it's difficult to say any more.

Comment: Kind of looks like part of the code got cut out. `\defaultfontfeatures` suggests XeLaTeX with `fontspec`, but this is appearing after the `ifPDFTeX` conditional and `fontspec` is nowhere to be seen. If this code was *really* generated by pandoc *as is*, I'd want to see the original input file and what options were used when calling pandoc.

Comment: @frabjous: I added the entire preamble. The code used to create the document in Pandoc was panic -o -s mydoc.docx mydoc.tex, or possibly pandoc -s -o output.tex input.docx I still don't understand why \section{text} fails to yield a numbered section. This is OK as I don't want the sections numbered, but I don't understand the behavior.

Comment: My original document had a few Unicode characters, so it was either try to find them (there are 70,000 lines) or switch to Lua-or Xe-LaTeX.The goal is a print document so hyperref isn't needed and I have no idea what the special commands are doing.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem with the new code either. Could you switch to just using `\lipsum` for the text contents (except whatever you need to trigger the problem)? Note that `\lipsum`'s argument goes in square brackets. `\lipsum[10]` or `\lipsum[10-20]`, not `\lipsum{20}`.

Comment: The lack of section numbers is caused by the line `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-\maxdimen} % remove section numbering`, btw.

Comment: Changed the text to lipsum and corrected the bracket error. Removing that line resulted in the sections being given numbers--unwanted but an easy fix--and a digit preceding the offending '[' as shown above.

Comment: The sections are now numbered: 0.1, 0.2 0.3 etc., so the verso header reads "0 [" throughout the text, which is unhelpful...

Comment: @frabjous: if you want to write your "the lack of section numbers" as an answer I will so mark it. I think the problem was a little more involved than that, but that ultimately was the error that caused the other issues.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136260/discussion-between-frabjous-and-user26732).